# StructureMap: using regular parameter unless configured in ObjectFactory

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, structuremap

I feel like I'm trying to accomplish something that's not quite the "StructureMap way", or maybe it is but I just don't know how to do it. I hope someone can help me with this:

I'm writing a plugin that is required to have an `Execute` method that gets passed in  an `IServiceProvider` (provided by the application running my plugin).
Currently, my code looks something like this:

```
public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    //The serviceProvider is used to extract references to other objects it supplies:
    this.Context = serviceProvider.GetService<IPluginExecutionContext>();

    //This could go more than one level deep:
    this.Acme = this.Context.Acme;

    //Do something with this.Context and this.Acme here...
}
```

This is fine for when running in production. However, when I unittest this plugin, I want to be able to insert my mocked versions of IPluginExecutionContext or Acme using StructureMap.

Now, I know how to have StructureMap register a concrete type for a particular interface:

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
{
    x.For<IPluginExecutionContext>()
     .Use<MockedPluginExecutionContext>();
});
```

But how do I get my Execute implementation to use this MockedPluginExecutionContext if configured, or use the value returned by `serviceProvider.GetService<IPluginExecutionContext>()` if it is not configured?

Answer (score 0):

Using NSubstitute I would do the following to test `Execute` in isolation (if that is what you want to do):

```
// arrange
var objectUnderTest = ...
var mockPluginExecContext = new MockedPluginExecutionContext();
var mockProvider = Substitute.For<IServiceProvider>();
mockProvider.GetService<IPluginExecutionContext>.Returns(mockPluginExecContext);

// act
objectUnderTest.Execute(mockProvider);

// assert
Assert.IsTrue(...);
```